# Error on create trigger: Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, merge

I have been doing this trigger to do a merge when inserted on the same table but apparently I keep getting this error :

```
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

**My trigger:**

```
create trigger [dbo].[Updated_table1]
on [dbo].[table1]
instead of INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
set nocount on;

IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED) = 0
    RETURN;


merge into  [dbo].[table1] with (HOLDLOCK) as d
using INSERTED as i 
on (i.[primarykey] = d.[primarykey])
when not matched then insert 
values ('...','...');

END
```

Any  ideas?

Comment: Error message sounds pretty self explanatory. Are the values matched to the columns properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicitly mention the `Target` and `Source` column names in your insert statement....

Something like this ........

```
create trigger [dbo].[Updated_table1]
on [dbo].[table1]
instead of INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
set nocount on;

IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED) = 0
    RETURN;


merge into  [dbo].[table1] with (HOLDLOCK) as d
using INSERTED as i 
on (i.[primarykey] = d.[primarykey])
when not matched then 
insert (d.Column1,d.Column2,d.Column3,d.Column4,...)
values (i.Column1,i.Column2,i.Column3,i.Column4,...)

END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TRIGGER tr_Emp_forInsert
On Emp
For Insert
AS
BEGIN

    Declare @Id int
    select @Id = ID from inserted

    insert into EmpAudit
    values('New employee with ID =  ' + cast (@Id as nvarchar(5))  + ' is added at ' 
    + cast (Getdate () as nvarchar(20)))
end
```

Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.